# R plot margins way too large when plotting networks in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I've searched SO and haven't found a solution that I can get to work.  I don't have any replicable data, but I've got the graph below illustrating my issue: my plot is too small.  Any ideas on what my issue might be? The picture below has about half of its area as white space.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the margin parameter using:

```
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0)+.1)
```

See more info on `par` here: http://rfunction.com/archives/1302

Answer (score 0):

Just in case that someone has a similar problem, you can change the margins by adding margins in plot:
`plot(g, layout = layout_nicely(g),... margin=0)`
See more details here: https://igraph.org/r/doc/plot.common.html

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything for my graph

Comment: That is because `margin=0` is the default.